# Using foreach() in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, foreach, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark DataFrame which contains a column named `primary_use`.

Here is the first row:

[image]

To create a boolean vector that will indicate whether the `primary_use` in a certain row is `Education` or `Office` I am using the following code.  However, it returns None which leads to an exception:

```
def is_included_in(row):
    
    return(row['primary_use'] in ['Education', 'Office'])

building.foreach(is_included_in).show()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-03dd626371bf> in <module>
----> 1 building.foreach(is_included_in).show()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'show'
```

Why do I get this result, and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

pyspark [foreach](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=foreach#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.foreach) does not produce a new transformed dataframe. `Foreach` allows to iterate over each record and perform some non-returning operation - e.g write to disk, or call some external api

Also the function actually calls `df.rdd.foreach`. Rdd is the underlying dataframe api. It is more low level. The proper rdd api to transform each record is [Rdd.map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=map#pyspark.RDD.map)

The dataframe api also provides the possibility to run scalar mapping user defined functions. The newest one is [pandas udf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html#pandas-udfs-aka-vectorized-udfs)

Such [isin](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=isin#pyspark.sql.Column.isin) function is already part of standard spark sql api.

```
df = df.withColumn('is_included', df.primary_use.isin(['Education', 'Office']))
```